# Is there any library in python that converts annotations in .ann format to .json for NER and RE models?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am (desperately) searching for some library or function or whatever useful to convert my annotations in `.ann` format to `.json` format. I need it in order to train and test some NER and RE model.

I am also trying to build my own function, but I can't totally understand how the indexes are calculated.

Furthermore, I'll give you an example I got using the `spacy` library in order to obtain a partial output file I would like to obtain.

Here it is my `.ann` file:

```
T1  Adverb 3 9  boldly
T2  Verb 10 12  go
T3  Verb 59 61  won
R0  Support Arg1:T1 Arg2:T2
```

Here it is my `.txt` file:

```
To boldly go where no one has gone before. God is Great! I won a lottery.
```

Using a function made by me, I built the `.conll` file as follows:

```
0   To  _   _   O
1   boldly  _   _   B-Adverb
2   go  _   _   B-Verb
3   where   _   _   O
4   no  _   _   O
5   one _   _   O
6   has _   _   O
7   gone    _   _   O
8   before. _   _   O

9   God _   _   O
10  is  _   _   O
11  Great!  _   _   O

12  I   _   _   O
13  won _   _   B-Verb
14  a   _   _   O
15  lottery.    _   _   O
```

After that I run the `spacy` cli command in order to obtain the `.json` file and I got this:

```
[
  {
    "id":0,
    "paragraphs":[
      {
        "raw":null,
        "sentences":[
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "id":0,
                "orth":"0",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"To",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":1,
                "orth":"1",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"boldly",
                "ner":"U-Adverb"
              },
              {
                "id":2,
                "orth":"2",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"go",
                "ner":"U-Verb"
              },
              {
                "id":3,
                "orth":"3",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"where",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":4,
                "orth":"4",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"no",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":5,
                "orth":"5",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"one",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":6,
                "orth":"6",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"has",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":7,
                "orth":"7",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"gone",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":8,
                "orth":"8",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"before.",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ],
            "brackets":[

            ]
          },
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "id":9,
                "orth":"9",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"God",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":10,
                "orth":"10",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"is",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":11,
                "orth":"11",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"Great!",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ],
            "brackets":[

            ]
          },
          {
            "tokens":[
              {
                "id":12,
                "orth":"12",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"I",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":13,
                "orth":"13",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"won",
                "ner":"U-Verb"
              },
              {
                "id":14,
                "orth":"14",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"a",
                "ner":"O"
              },
              {
                "id":15,
                "orth":"15",
                "space":" ",
                "tag":"lottery.",
                "ner":"O"
              }
            ],
            "brackets":[

            ]
          }
        ],
        "cats":[

        ],
        "entities":[
          [
            2,
            3,
            "Adverb"
          ],
          [
            4,
            5,
            "Verb"
          ],
          [
            29,
            31,
            "Verb"
          ]
        ],
        "links":[

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Said that, my questions and problems are:

1. **How are calculated the indexes of the entities?** They're very different from the indexes present in the `.ann` file
2. **Is there a way to include the relations in the same `.json` output file?**

Here it is an example provided in the GitHub repo of the NER and RE model that require to be trained:

```
{
  "clusters": [],
  "sentences": [
    [
      "We",
      "describe",
      "a",
      "dialogue",
      "system",
      "that",
      "works",
      "with",
      "its",
      "interlocutor",
      "to",
      "identify",
      "objects",
      "."
    ],
    [
      "Our",
      "contributions",
      "include",
      "a",
      "concise",
      ",",
      "modular",
      "architecture",
      "with",
      "reversible",
      "processes",
      "of",
      "understanding",
      "and",
      "generation",
      ",",
      "an",
      "information-state",
      "model",
      "of",
      "reference",
      ",",
      "and",
      "flexible",
      "links",
      "between",
      "semantics",
      "and",
      "collaborative",
      "problem",
      "solving",
      "."
    ]
  ],
  "ner": [
    [
      [
        3,
        4,
        "Method"
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        18,
        21,
        "Method"
      ],
      [
        26,
        26,
        "Task"
      ],
      [
        28,
        28,
        "Task"
      ],
      [
        31,
        34,
        "Method"
      ],
      [
        40,
        40,
        "OtherScientificTerm"
      ],
      [
        42,
        44,
        "Task"
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "relations": [
    [],
    [
      [
        18,
        21,
        26,
        26,
        "USED-FOR"
      ],
      [
        18,
        21,
        28,
        28,
        "USED-FOR"
      ],
      [
        26,
        26,
        28,
        28,
        "CONJUNCTION"
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "doc_key": "P05-3001"
}
```

Thank you in advance for who will help me to solve this desperately task of my PhD.

Answer (score 0):

So to clear something up, JSON data **is NOT required** to train a spaCy model. In v2 it was the normal way to train a model, but in v3 you just need to make a DocBin, which you can make from a list of Docs. This means the data format doesn't matter, you just have to figure out how to map your annotations to Docs. So data conversion looks like:

1. Put raw text into spaCy to get a Doc object
2. Figure out how to map your annotations to the Doc by setting entities etc., dealing with tokenization differences
3. Save the Docs ([documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading/#docs))

The [training data docs](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data) may be helpful.

You seem to be referring to the [relation extraction sample project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/rel_component), which has JSON data, but only uses it as input to this process. You really don't have to worry about the format it uses.

It's difficult to say exactly how you should convert the data, because you seem to have given a partial sample of your `.ann` data. What program produced it? How do you get the original text? It looks like it uses character annotations, but how do you know if there are spaces between two tokens or not?

You should looks at the training data docs and take a good look at how the [data preparation script](https://github.com/explosion/projects/blob/v3/tutorials/rel_component/scripts/parse_data.py) creates the Docs.

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for your help @polm23 . In my case, I don't have to train any spaCy model, but other models for NER and RE tasks (like this [https://github.com/princeton-nlp/PURE#Input-data-format-for-the-entity-model](one) ). My worst concern is to understand how the indexes used to indicate the beginning and the end of the entities, and for the relations as well. I tried to figured out the one got in spaCy but, to me it doesn't make any sense since they don't refer to the char index, token index or BIO index...

Comment: Huh, I'm not really sure I understand - were you not trying to convert from the ANN format to the spaCy JSON format? If you have a separate library that uses JSON input it probably doesn't use the spaCy JSON format. In the spaCy JSON, I see token indices in the `entities` section and no character indices, I'm not really sure what's unclear about it?

Comment: OK, I guess I see what you mean now. The JSON format at your link is definitely not the spaCy format, and is only slightly similar. It looks like they specify spans with token indices but the indices are inclusive, so something like `[12, 12, "XYZ"]` is a span of length 1 (spaCy uses exclusive end indices). For relations, it's like `[span1_start, span1_end, span2_start, span2_end, label]`. I suggest you ask about the format at that repo, it doesn't look standard.

Comment: Yes, the problem is to understand how to use the index in order to let the model train. Thank you so much for your explanation and your time!